Nikon always says subject too dark when taking night pics
I have a Nikon D3300 and am trying to take night sky pics. I watched a YouTube video of a guy using the exact camera and doing it. I set mine to manual and all the exact settings and have it on a tripod and can’t get past subject too dark message no matter what I do. Anyone have any idea how to get past that.

Are you sure that you are in Manual mode? That is, Manual exposure, but I think manual focus is pretty essential too.

To expand on the comment by @osullic if the camera is in an auto focus mode, then it is unlikely to be able to focus before taking an image.

In full manual including manual focus the camera should be completely agnostic (uncaring) about subject brightness.
